# What will happen if one domain couldn't cancel the effect of other domain?

Tags: electrons

According to quantam mechanical effect an unpaired electron in one atom interacts strongly with the unpaired electron in the neighbouring atom in such a way that they align them self in a common direction over a small volume of a material called domain.
In the absence of the direction magnetic movement in different domains are oriented randomly in different direction.
This results that one domain cancel the effect of other and net magnetic movement of the material is "zero".

Comment: The material will be magnetized, at least partially.